# Using same .sty-file on different computers

Tags: packages, preamble

I use a .sty-file where I collect all packages and commands and stuff like that. This I have on my personal computer, and I load the file with

```
\usepackage{path/to/file}
```

Sometimes I have to write on my work computer, or sync git projects on other computers. Is there a way to use the same style-file across all these computers and locations? The path to the file is different for every computer. I could have the .sty-file everywhere, and just give the location, but when I commit it to a git project to use it on a different computer, I have to change the location again. Sorry for the confused attempts to explain the problem, but is there a way to use the same .sty-file on different computers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On each computer you wish to use, create a link in your home directory that points to the actual file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: On a Unix/Linux/MacOS system each user has a  `texmf`  directory, where own fonts and packages can be stored

Comment: Put your local `texmf` folder in Dropbox (or equivalent) and then make symbolic links in each computer to the Dropbox folder.  See [Centralised .bib file on Mac](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/337952) for how to do this on a Mac, but the principle is the same for any unix based system. (No idea about Windows).  BTW, the argument to `\usepackage` is *not* a path. Use your `texmf` folder properly and you shouldn't need to specify paths in `\usepackage` commands ever.

Comment: `\usepackage` should just have the filename not the path, cf `\usepackage{array}`  not `\usepackage{/usr/local/...tex/latex/tools/array}`  just place your file.sty file in a directory in the TEXINPUTS path on both machines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is a very intriguing idea. I have never heard of it before. Could you please provide some details on how to put .sty there? I don't seem to find TEXINPUTS for instance.  Thanks.